# how to get key names and length of nested json's in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript, I get the following JSON from my API.

```
abc: {
    a: {
        name: "ascs"
    },
    b: {
        name: "sddd"
    },
    c: {
        name: "wede"
    }
}
```

I need to find following:

1. How do calculate length of json inside abc JSON ?
2. How do i get keys name [a,b,c] from abc JSON ?

if i have another json :

```
data : {
"5.5": {
name :"bhagvat"
 }
}
```

1. in above case how do i get the value of name ?

(how to deal with float keys)? i try with ===> data."5.5".name

Comment: What do you mean by length inside abc JSON?

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @Nikhil i need to get number of json inside abc json

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of object and then use `.length` for number of json inside `abc` json.

```js
var abc = {
  a: {
    name : "ascs"
   },
  b : {
   name : "sddd" 
  },
  c: {
   name :"wede"
   }
 };
 
 var keys = Object.keys(abc);
 var length = keys.length;
 console.log('key is ',keys);
 console.log('length is '+length);
```

Comment: You missed second part _how do i get keys name [a,b,c] from abc JSON ?_

Comment: @Satpal it's there. using `+` in console.log changes the array to string so you got to see string representation. Updated now.

Comment: Also may be OP needs `console.log(Object.keys(abc).map(x => abc[x].name));`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object/keys)

```js
let abc = { a: {name: "ascs"},b: {name: "sddd"},c: {name: "wede"}};
let keys = Object.keys(abc);
console.log(keys); // paints keys
let length = keys.length;
console.log(length); // paints the number of keys
```

**EDIT**

To extract the value you bracket notation

```js
let data = {5.5 : {name: "bhagvat"}};

console.log(data["5.5"].name);
```

Comment: thanks for this one , can you also tell me if i have float as json key for ex: data: { 5.5  { name:"bhagvat"   } }  in this case how did i get value of name , itry with data.5.5.name it fails .

Comment: @BhagvatLande, seems you need `Object.keys(abc).map(x => abc[x].name);`

Answer (score 1):

To get the key names you can use Object.keys().

```
const abc = {
  a: {
    name : "ascs"
     },
  b : {
   name : "sddd" 
    },
 c: {
 name :"wede"
   }
 }
 const abcKeyNames = Object.keys(abc);
```

This will return an array of key names in the object.
Not sure what you mean by length of object but I think you mean how many keys are in this object? you can use Array.length()

```
const abcLength = abcKeyNames.length()
```

This will return how many elements are in this array.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax),

```
let keys = [...abc];

console.log(keys.length); // to get keys length in json

console.log(keys); //to get the keys
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object/keys)

```
let data = { "10.5": {"XYZ": "ABC"},"10.6": {"PQR": "LMN"}};
let keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log(keys); // ["10.5","10.6"]
let length = keys.length;
console.log(length); // 2
```

For accessing element using float key

```
let xyz = data["10.5"];
```

Comment: use it like let ABC = data["10.5"].XYZ;

Answer (score 0):

Get this json in "var data" then the folloing answers works :

1. how do calculate length of json inside abc JSON ?
   Ans : Object.keys(data.abc).length;
2. how do i get keys name [a,b,c] from abc JSON ?
   Ans : data.abc.a["name"]
     data.abc.b["name"]